# SQL: Efficiently Calculate Time Spent

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join, group-by

Given a list of event timestamps, how do you calculate the "time spent"? The "time spent" is the sum of the time intervals between each timestamp, ignoring intervals above a certain threshold, e.g. 1 minute, during which the user was probably inactive.

I tried something like this:

```
select sum(finish - start)
from (select start.time as start,
             finish.time as finish
      from events start, events finish
      where start.time < finish.time and
            finish.time - start.time < interval '1 minute'
      group by start.time) as intervals;
```

But this proved vastly inefficient and never terminated.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected results ? That would be helping others to help you quickly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT SUM ( time_interval_up_to_1_min )
FROM (
  SELECT 
        CASE WHEN time - lag( time ) over (ORDER BY time) 
                <= interval '1' minute
             THEN time - lag( time ) over (ORDER BY time)
        END As time_interval_up_to_1_min
  FROM events
) x
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6f814/7

Comment: Why is this more efficient than a join?

Comment: The above query reads the data from the table only once, while the join must read the table twice and combine rows from both data sources which is more expensive than simple read.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(time-lag(time) over (order by time)) from events
```

I'm not sure why you're joining events to itself in that fashion but that's most likely why the query is running forever, not because of the trivial aggregate calculation.

Comment: That does not satisfy "ignore intervals of more than 1 minute". But yes, window functions are the answer.